# How can I edit multiple users info in one page?

Tags: python, django, templates, view

Lets say I want to make a page in my website where I want to be able to enter in the DB if workers are present or not.

Every worker has separate profile page.

My `models.py`:

```
class profile(models.Model):
    ...#other fields
    username = model.Charfield(max_length=26, blank=false)

class attendence(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(profile, related_name='attendence')
    28January2018 = models.BooleanField(default=1)
```

Prototype Picture:
[image: Prototype Picture]

In the prototype picture, if it is green it should be True in the boolean field, means present (this is the defualt), and when I click their name, the booleanfield will be false means absent and it will be red.

How can achieve this? I need the template and the view code.

Comment: i can write it for you but the point is your question is too global try something first and then ask in stackoverflow read django's docs

Comment: I have learnt to edit one user's data so far, I'm not able to do the same for many users. Just give me some hints. You don't need to write the whole code.

Comment: Well, I have started to figure out something. Till now, in the view I had forms where the user was one but field were many, here the field is one but users are many.

Comment: hope my answer helps you man if you need something just comment and ill reach you :)

Comment: Still, I'm not able to create the form where users will be many but the DB field will be one. Should i create multiple forms in one page?Can you refer to some tutorials or anything else?

Comment: ok wait you want `onClick listener` onto the user name, if clicked -> the user is not present is that that you want? Instead of using the forms better use ajax

Comment: Yes, but I never used Ajax. I've seen some tuts before. Ok, so in your way of doing that, the True/Flase will be updated in front end, then how can I store that info in DB.

Comment: yeah Just on each click will up[date the database in real time

Comment: No, no. I don't want this. I want the info to be updated only if the admin clicks on Save or Save and keep editing. Cant I do this with Ajax?

Comment: You didn't response :-|

Comment: man it's too complicated to do all of your job just try something read books watch tutorials...

Comment: Ok, I'll. But, tell me if that is possible or not.

Comment: yes it is possible man

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## OKAY..

So first you create your view to populate the form

```
def populate_my_form(request):
  context = {}
  context['users'] = Users.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'myapp/my_template.html', context)
```

in your template you should have something like

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 <form action="{{ url 'post_my_edits' }}" method="get" id="employees">
      {% for user in users%}
        #store the data in hidden inputs will be easier for you to understand id  
        <input id="input_for_user_{{user.id}}" name="{{user.id}}" value="{{user.is_present}}" style="display:none" type="text" disabled> 
      <div id="{{user.id}}"  class="user_is_present {{user.is_present}}">{{user.first_name}}</div>
      {% endfor %}
 </form> 

<button type="submit" form="employees" value="Submit">Submit</button>
<script>  
          $('.user_is_present').click(function(){
            my_input = $("#input_for_user_"+$(this).attr('id'))
            if( my_input.val() === 'present'){
               $(this).removeClass( "present" )
               $(this).addClass("absent")
               my_input.val("absent")
            }
            if( my_input.val() === 'absent'){
               $(this).removeClass( "absent" )
               $(this).addClass("present")
               my_input.val("present")
            }
        })

</script>
```

in the js go

assuming in your urls have an url

```
path('update_users/', views.update_users, name='update_users')
```

and a view

```
def update_users(request):
    for user in Users.objects.all():
        user.is_present = request.POST[str(user.id)]
        user.save()

    context = {}
    context['users'] = Users.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'myapp/my_template.html', context)
```

in you css

```
.user_is_present{
 height:50px;
 width:100px;
}
.present{
 background-color:green;
}
.absent{
 background-color:red;
}
```

a litte code repeating but sorry im trying to show you the technique then you read some more and you will improove ;)

## recap

whever you clik on an user it will change the background color and their statuses after submit will save the information to your users

Comment: After you advised to look on the internet, I had checked a couple of tutorials till now. Still, thanks for the effort uou took to write the anser. I've some bug to fix for now. I'll try your code ASAP.

Comment: Another thing, I need to know, why there's two context at the first code.

Comment: Just creating the object context first and then fill it up with data